# Keeping a public and private version of my app using Git

Tags: git, version-control, branch, versioning

I am building a Rails app that I manage with Git. All is perfect, but I'd like keep a public version as well as a private one. That is:

- the public version is for a public repository  (for people to use),
- and the private version is for my own site.

The idea is that both versions should be up-to-date, with the difference that my private version's files contain passwords for my site, and the public version doesn't (or contains some default values as such).

I've been thinking of branches: `master` (the public version) and some private one.
But it seems that I'd have to do a lot of merging after each commit.

Please, bear in mind, that I am a asking for I am still quite a noob at git.

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do Django development and keep all my sensitive data inside a single file which I put inside my `.gitignore`. It's not version controlled and I keep separate versions of this on my deployment server and local dev machine.

Comment: Yeah. Right. I could be simple :-D Thanks! I could actually have defaults preset, and then overwrite them using some one-place config.

Comment: Superior ability breeds superior Ambition - Spock. ;)

Comment: +1. I like the simplicity of it, but as you said, my method is a generic one.

Answer (score 4):

I would:

- store the password in a private repo which contains only sensitive data
- store in the public repo:

  - a reference to the private repo as a submodule (only you could checkout that submodule, since it is a private repo)
  - some template config
  - some script able to build the actual config file with the right value:

    - default value if there is no submodule
    - passwords if the submodule is checked-out.

That way, no merge whatsoever, and no way to push sensitive data to a public repo.

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that I'd use Noufal's method, but thanks for the general ideas!